# Setting Gatling to send requests based on percentage/ratios?

Tags: java, performance, scala, testing, gatling

I want to setup Gatling so that in one setup, I can send 3000 requests, of which 95% will use one test file, and 5% another test file. These files are retrieved as json files (called 'userFeeder' in below code. Can Gatling support the above scenario?

The code is currently as follows, which works for a request per second approach, but needs amending.

```
class AddUserSimulation extends Simulation {

  private val conf = ConfigFactory.load() //loads a setup file of parameters
  private val TOKEN_VALUE = "tokenvalue"
  private val userFeeder =  jsonFile("/" + conf.getString("environment") + "/testaddUser.json")

  val httpConf = http
    .baseURL(conf.getString("api.gateway.url")) // Here is the root for all relative URLs
    .header("Referer", conf.getString("referer"))
    .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    .contentTypeHeader("application/json")

  val Login = new ADFSAuthentication Login

  val scnAPI = scenario("test add User") // A scenario is a chain of requests and pauses
    .feed(userFeeder.circular)
    .exec(Login.process)
    .repeat(conf.getInt("repeat.count")) {
        exec(http("test add User")
        .post("/" + conf.getString("environment") + "/users/")
        .body(StringBody("${payload}")).asJSON
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer ${"+TOKEN_VALUE+"}")
    .check(status.is(200)))
    .pause(conf.getInt("execution.pause"))
    }
  setUp(scnAPI.inject(constantUsersPerSec(11) during(30 minutes)).protocols(httpConf)) 
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! First set up your two feeders. Then set up two scenarios, one using the first feeder, one using the second feeder. Finally `setUp` both with the number of users you wish (corresponding to your distribution).

The code could look something like this:

```
private val firstFeeder =  jsonFile("/" + conf.getString("environment") + "/testaddUser.json")
private val secondFeeder =  jsonFile("/" + conf.getString("environment") + "/testaddUser2.json")

val scnAPI = scenario("test add User")
    .feed(firstFeeder)
    //...

val scnAPI2 = scenario("second test add User")
    .feed(secondFeeder)
    //...

setUp(scnAPI.inject(constantUsersPerSec(95) during(30 minutes)).protocols(httpConf), 
      scnAPI2.inject(constantUsersPerSec(5) during(30 minutes)).protocols(httpConf))
```

Note: This will not create exactly 3000 requests but I think you get the idea.

Comment: That is exactly what we used eventually. Thanks for this input, using two feeders was the solution.